# How to verify observe or check the source of AC line noise

Tags: ac, noise

I'm using a complicated system which reads pressure measurements and sends to an ADC. I will not go to details of the system because I just noticed a big difference due to different AC mains connections.

Below is a basic illustration of the system:

[image]

The system is always in the second floor. If I plug the AC power cord to the mains in 2nd floor I get a very noisy spiky output. Both with 2 prong and 3 prong connector. So it seems its not earth related.

But if I leave the system in the second floor and plug the AC power cord in the 1st floor I get a very clean output.

Below shows this difference. Both voltage is on vertical axis represents sensor data and scaled with factor 100.(For example 10 in vertical pressure axis is 0.1 Volt). These wild spikes are like HF noise.

[image]

I tested it many times and I'm sure this is the source of the noise.
The place in the 2nd floor has an AC motor and florescent lambs. But this happens some days. Some days not.

I mean if I use the mains power in 2nd floor for powering up the system I observe this on some days.

But if I use the 1st floor's plug there is never noise.

Something is causing noise on AC lines in the second floor.

Since neutrals are all connected in a building could it be the live is being exposed to noise in 2nd floor?

Can I measure/verify this with noise with a scope and a step down transformer? Or with an RC differentiator?

Comment: Are you sure the outlets on the second floor are wired properly with real earth grounds?  I've seen lots of AC outlets that are mis-wired, you might check that first.

Comment: Switch off everything until the noise goes away, then you just switched off the noise source.

Comment: @JohnD If I plug the AC mains in the 1st floor with 2 prong cable(no earth) there is no noise. Do you think it can be related to earth?

Comment: Your time scale isn't fast enough to show details of those noise spikes. Can you speed up the timescale? It may be related to the line frequency. Those spikes may be fast enough that you can track them down by waving a scope probe around your 2nd floor room.

Comment: @glen_geek Yes the sampling rate is only 500Hz. I'm planning to use a scope after stepping down the AC voltage to 12V by a transformer not to harm the scope. Would FFT help or an RC differentiator reveals the spikes in time domain? Which one is better to observe the HF components and harmonics?

Comment: FFT would be great if the frequency scale doesn't go past about 200Khz. Motor noise is often a series of 60 Hz harmonics.

Comment: This is very weird situation for me. Beacuse last week the noise wasnt there but this week it is back. I tried last week when motor and VFD and fluorescent lambs is on there was no noise with 2nd floor plug, But this week there is. Can it be the source of the AC line noise coming from outside pheomena or other utlities outside of the building only for 2nd floor?

Comment: I had to open a new question directly related to this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274622/power-supply-noise-problem-in-a-measurement-system

Comment: you should include your floor location information and different AC results into the main question, I think it is important. Also, you didn't say for how long the interference lasts, is it in short bursts, or runs continuously for minutes or hours.

Comment: @noise lasts some times 4 hours sometimes a day. someday it is not there. sometimes when everything is running it is not there(i mean all motors vfds what so ever). but sometimes when everything is off even the lights it is there it differs depending on the AC mains outlet(second floor or first floor) regardless of earth connection (2 prong 3 prong no matter). Im sure it is not being effected by in building appliance. it is coming from outside and it is only coming to a particular line.

Comment: i was really suspicious of the power supply that it is being effected from this ac line noise.