# Does FFT plot in an oscilloscope indicates the division or span of the frequency?

Tags: oscillator, fft

When measuring voltages V per division is indicated. If the scope shows 10mV/div it means each square's horizontal edge represents 10mV.

Is that the same with FFT graph?

Here is an example:

[image]

The reason I'm asking is that in my previous question it was said that this might belong to a 80kHz switching device.

I thought in the above FFT picture each square represents 250kHz before.
But now I'm confused. Is 250kHz per div(per horizontal square) or the entire span which is 10 horizontal square edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFT function transforms a time series of samples into frequency domain. Your sampling rate is 5Ms/s, so the entire FFT span should be 2.5MHz. There is 10 divisions, so your horizontal scale is 250kHz/div, as the scope says, with center at 1.25MHz.

The spectrum of this kind belongs to a signal consisting of very narrow ( = high bandwidth) spikes at some regular fundamental frequency. This frequency can be estimated from spacing of its higher harmonics. I estimate about 7.2 spikes over two divisions, which means that the fundamental frequency of the spikes is about 500/7.2 ~ 70kHz.

Due to high bandwidth of the signal, the spectrum is contaminated by aliases. You can improve your measurement by doubling sampling frequency (gives less aliases) and doubling/quadrupling the length of data acquisition (give better frequency resolution). But even in the given form, this spectrum is good enough to make rough conclusion on the nature of signal.

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/equipment/TEKtds1002.pdf) for the TDS1000/2000-series reveals the following (hidden on page 119):

[image]

To get a better reading of the frequency it is possible to zoom (p. 124) or to use the cursors to make a measurement (p. 126).

Comment: So it is per div. This might be 800kHz not 80kHz switching?

Comment: See the update. And yes, looks more like 80kHz.

Comment: but the highest freq. component appears around the 3rd square which becomes 3*250kHz around 800kHz. What am I thinking wrong here? Im talking about my picture in my question.

Comment: Im asking abut the plot in my question. Is that 800khZ or 80Hz?

Comment: Why don't you use the cursor measurement function of your scope? It's much more reliable than my guess.

Comment: Im asking the  peak freq component in my pic is around 800kHz do you agree???? But some says this FFT belongs to a 80kHz switching. What do you think? How would you interpret this spectrum? Cursor is just for detailed reading Im not asking that.

Comment: @doncarlos, Mario is simply asking you to put two cursors on two nearby peaks, and read the difference.

Comment: I'm seeing about 68 KHz. No doubt it is all chopped up at some other (probably lower) frequency. Or its really "spikey" 68 KHz.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also seeing like @glen_geek, the narrow edges of 68kHz alternating pulses as the fundamental is attenuated from the traditional sin(x)/x curve by a high pass filter effect.  This  averaged as 11 dominant spikes over 3 divisions. Since there are several envelopes to the spectrum we can assume they are basically the edges that dominate this signal and that the duty cycle is not 50% so there are spectral envelopes for each polarity of the spike with slightly different rise times and pulse widths.  ( we know in Fourier Spectrum there is a minimum for the sine wave that fits at the minimum or null)

Perhaps you should consider lower ESR caps in parallel with your SMPS storage caps as the spectral noise looks too flat or better a CLC Pi filter.

[image]

Of course it may be just unintended radiation from poor CM rejection and lack of CM filtering or simply measurement error.

Comment: Should I unplug all the equipment from the mains to find it? Should I use a ferrite bead or something like this: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/iec-filters/0238817/

Comment: This is related to this issue: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274622/power-supply-noise-problem-in-a-measurement-system/274823#274823 In my previous question I asked for a quick solution, Im planning to cut the cable and place 100nF caps between +15V to GND and -15V to GND. Do you think it can be a solution? Using 10uF decoupling caps before the module I mean.

Comment: First measure if it is conducted or radiated crosstalk.   I don't know how your system is grounded or even your scope probe.  Can you markup https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ervix.png  Radiated can be easily measured with a scope ground lead loop in same proximity to noise.  CM and DM noise is fixed differently. Common mode is easily measure using probe as an antenna with a piece of wire. Conducted CM noise is measured by a shorted loop around offending cable.

Comment: I found out that the noise is not only at that system. I brought a supply to the same floor and the noise was there. The scope is not earthed to eliminate the scope noise. If I even monitor the disconnected power supply in the 2nd floor I see this noise. I think the noise is in the earth bouncing and if the power supply is using the earth it is effected from the earth. And if totally disconnected from mains it is picking up same noise through the air. So both.. But surprisingly less noise if I use 2 prong connected to mains but still there. I guess the earth ground or neutral or line is noisy.

Comment: Im sure there is radiated noise but the source of it is the AC lines or earth. Something is sometimes corrupting one of these lines at second floor and the line also radiated like an antenna and inject EMI. Thstas my assumption after such tests. I cannot get any answer about decoupling caps method. I have to cut that special cable to place the caps thats why I wanted to ask here.

Comment: old SMPS may not have a good Line filter. get one. There is a lot of capacitance coupling of CM noise. Ferrite sleeves over cables help but a solid ground reference for the system absorbs all the noise better in your measurement system using braided cable between devices to earth ground or some reference.  A noise laptop charger for example can be suppressed by connecting to a external grounded monitor.

Comment: Do you think this would be worth to try out before the entire system: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/iec-filters/0238817/ ??

Comment: Certainly , but why guess when this can be determined with a scope probe and earth grounding DC outputs and probing as I suggested. As long as 3A is sufficient.

Comment: If it is conducted then probe on signal to good ground with short leads will show it.  If radiated then probe open loop antenna wire or closed loop around cable will see it. There are combinations of variables CM,DM Conducted and Radiated.  Unbalanced signal cables convert CM noise into DM noise.